# css menu bar with 2 items (left-end and right-end)

Tags: css, menu, position

I cannot find the solution on the web. So I post here.

I want to create a bar with 2 items, one at the left-end, and one at the the right-end :

'text' ... ... 'img'.

'img', because I'm also looking how to place an icon...

Here's what I want : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQK0kz65wpo&list=UUpOIUW62tnJTtpWFABxWZ8g
See at 9:07.

Unfortunately, he doesn't tell how he does that in his tutorial.

You can see there's an empty element between 'Menu' and the icon.

```
<div>
    <div class="handle">Menu</div>
    <div class="icon"></span>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Patrick

Comment: Please post your code. This can be easily done by wrapping the text 'text' and 'img' in two different `<div>`'s and then floating the first `<div>` to left and the second `<div>` to right.

Comment: thanks, <div>
    <div class="handle">Menu</div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
</div>, so icon float right, and then ?   I don't see the element in between, like in the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dq8z192L/77/).

HTML:

```
<html>
     <body>
          <div>
              <div class="handle">Text goes here</div>
              <div class="icon">Image goes here: <img src="" /></div>
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.handle {
    float: left;  
} 

.icon {
    float: right;  
}     
</style>
```

Comment: thanks! but in the video, you can see an empty element selected between 'Menu' and the icon. How he does that?

Comment: Are you referring to the click-able part in between the 'Menu' text and the icon?

Comment: Yes, that click-able part.

Comment: Thanks!  ... still nothing between 'Menu' and icon.

Comment: Actually there's no element, in between the 'Menu' and the icon, in the video which you've quoted. It's a simple anchor tag inside which the text is aligned to the left and the icon to the right. Since it's an anchor tag, you can click anywhere on it. The highlight which you're referring to as the empty element, at 9:07 in the video, is just the empty space between the text and the icon.